# Concat numbers from JSON without doublequotes using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have files with 1 json document per row and the fields `start_id` and `end_id` in each document. I'd like to use jq to extract these and print them on the same row.

So far I have:

```
cat part* | jq '"\(.start_id) \(.end_id)"' | sed s/\"//g | head
```

This works, but I need the `sed` to remove the double quotes.

In order to improve my jq-foo, is there a way to do this *without using sed*?

e.g. given

```
{"start_id":1,"end_id":50}
{"start_id":50,"end_id":99}
{"start_id":99,"end_id":12}
```

get

```
1 50
50 99
99 12
```

instead of

```
"1 50"
"50 99"
"99 12"
```

Comment: Don't have a console on hand, but you could try runnign jq with `--raw-output` parameter

Answer (score 61, accepted):

By default, `jq` formats its output to be a valid JSON value. This means that character strings are wrapped in quotes.

Fortunately, the `--raw-output` or `-r` [parameter overrides](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) that behaviour so your string output can be free of those nasty quotation marks.