# Bash dialog menu options as array

Tags: bash, shell, dialog, stdout, jq

I get a http response of the Hetzner API which provides information about all volumes. I want to build a menu with dialog, where you can choose out of all existing volumes. 
This way I get the API's answer:

```
ALL_VOLUMES_HTTP=$(curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -H "Authorization: Bearer $1" https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes)
```

which is filtered by jq in this way

```
ALL_VOLUME_NAMES=$(jq '.volumes[].name' <<< "$ALL_VOLUMES_HTTP")
```

the output of `ALL_VOLUME_NAMES` is formatted like this

```
"volumeName1"
"volumeName2"
```

but in the menu dialog it is displayed [like in  this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByXBv.png)

I already tried to put brackets about the jq (`jq '[.volumes[].name'`) but it is displayed completely wrong too [like in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h4Nq.png)

For generating the interface I am using the following code:

```
SELECTED_VOLUME=$(dialog --title "Volume mount" --menu "Select:" 0 0 0 $ALL_VOLUME_NAMES 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

So how can I generate a correct menu interface in dialog with the given data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concat numbers from JSON without doublequotes using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947584/concat-numbers-from-json-without-doublequotes-using-jq)

Comment: It's not clear how the GUI menu is generated from the jq output. Please clarify, otherwise your Q is in danger of being closed. Also the filter mentioned in the Q (`'[.volumes[].name'`) is syntactically invalid, so you must have mistyped it when writing the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to concat the information to one string. This results in this code:

```
ALL_VOLUMES_HTTP=$(curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -H "Authorization: Bearer $1" https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes)
ALL_VOLUME_NAMES=$(echo $ALL_VOLUMES_HTTP | jq -r '.volumes[].name')

VALUES=""
for i in $ALL_VOLUME_NAMES; do
        VALUES="$VALUES $(jq -r '.volumes[]|select(.name=="'$i'")|.id' <<< "$ALL_VOLUMES_HTTP") $i"
done

SELECTED_VOLUME=$(dialog --title "Volume mount" --menu "Select: " 0 0 0 $VALUES 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```